# Height percentages won't work in CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I'm having some trouble getting percentages set to heights in CSS using the calc function. The calc function and percentages work with widths but will not work with heights. I'm trying to set a div with an ID of body and wants the height to be 100% - 70px. Please help as i need to get this completed soon.

Thanks, Jayden

Comment: usually is helpful to show what you have actually tried, i.e. some code, etc.

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem and post you code here so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Using percent means it is based on the parent's height. if the parent's size is 0, then you will have 0 also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Special case for `height`, you need to make sure all the element parents has `height` css property. Set your html, body heigth to 100% too. By set the height of parent element, you will able to set height of your element.

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
#element{
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I added height to 100% to height but it didn't Work, please be more specific :)